# Translation for “Made by” or typical Latin equivalent

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I’m looking for the correct way to say “made by” or “created by” for a custom garment tag. I have heard of "fecit" coming after a name but I’m thinking about bookplates and the “ex Libris” header as the inspiration. Is there an equivalent for this phrase?

Comment: Welcome to the site! And nice question!

Comment: Hi! It seems that you have created two accounts, as the first one was not registered. You will get more out of your question (notifications of comments and answers, ability to edit freely etc.) if you combine your two accounts. [See this instruction page for details.](https://latin.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 2):

In early modern Europe, the common phrase was *ex officina* (from the workshop), followed by the establishment's name, either in the genitive or as an adjective.

I think a practical way of implementing this in a modern, non-Latin-literate context is to put *ex officina* but keep your name or the name of your company in its normal form.

Answer (score 2):

As you mention, probably the oldest phrase for this would be *[name] mē fēcit*: literally, "[name] made me". (In each of the examples below, the first line is a direct transcription of the original, the second line is a translation/adaptation into standard Classical Latin, and the third is an English translation.)

The oldest attestation for this phrase is on the Praenestine Fibula, from the early seventh century BCE:

[image: Image of the Fibula]

> MANIOS MED FHEFHAKED NVMASIOI
>   Manius mē fēcit Numasiō
>   *Manius made me, for Numasius*

This remained popular all the way through the High Middle Ages:

[image: Image of an inscription]

This is from the south portal of the Church of Santa María la Real, in Sangüesa.

> MARIA MATER ΧΡΙ[ΣΤΟΥ] / LEODEGARIVS ME FECIT
>   Marīa, Mater Christī / Leodegarius mē fēcit
>   *Maria, Mother of Christ / Leodegarius made me*

Sometimes the inscription was varied or elaborated further, with forms like *[name] artifex mē fēcit*, or *[name] fēcit hoc*. But *fēcit* seems to be the verb form of choice. [This page](http://www.magistricataloniae.org/en/indexmceng/terms/item/fecit.html) lists some more examples.